# Avoid caching JS, CSS files page after each deployment

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net, caching

We are using ASP.Net. But in the front end, we are using HTML pages. So server side code could not used there.
By implementing like this  "login.js?s09809808098" we can resolve this. But we can't manually edit this on every pages before each deployment. Is there any method to edit the html pages in server side when a page is requested. Or any other method to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding expiration headers and dont cache headers to fix this problem.
You can also create a center repo for static URL assests and when your repo return the URL append a software version like login.js?v1 this way you will get new version with every release. also define the version number as a property in the repo class.

```
public static class URLRepo {
    public string AppVersion = "1";
    public string GetURL (enumURLName urls)
    {
     switch(enumURLName)
     {
       case enumURLName.LoginJS
            return "Login.JS?v" + AppVersion;
            break;
     }
    }
}
public enum enumURLName
{
   LoginJS,
   LoginCSS
}
```